# Neo4j, Cypher: Match the "group" comprising specific "users" only

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `(:User)` nodes which are grouped `[:IN]` `(:Group)` nodes.

```
CREATE (u1:User {name: 'u1'}), (u2:User {name: 'u2'}), (u3:User {name: 'u3'})
CREATE (g1:Group {name: 'g1'}), (g2:Group {name: 'g2'})
CREATE u1-[:IN]->g1, u2-[:IN]->g1, u3-[:IN]->g1
CREATE u1-[:IN]->g2, u2-[:IN]->g2
RETURN *
```

Given *"u1"* and *"u2"* I want to find out which `(:Group)` they **ALONE** belong to, i.e. *"g2."* My first attempt is **INCORRECT**:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name IN ['u1', 'u2']
WITH u
MATCH (u)-[:IN]->(g:Group)
RETURN g, collect(u)
```

It understandably returns the two `(:Group)`'s these users belong to.

How would find out that *"u1"* and *"u2"* alone belong to *"g2?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (g:Group)<--(m:User)
WITH g, collect(m) AS m
WHERE length(m) = 2 AND ALL (u IN m WHERE u.name IN ['u1','u2'])
RETURN *
```

to make sure that the group not only contains 2 users but those users are u1 and u2

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Luanne! Do you think it's efficient?

Comment: The query doesn't test that there are two users in the group. What happens if `u1` also belongs to (and is alone in) a group `g3`?

Comment: @GrantShield You can profile the queries to see how efficient they are, either in your own `neo4j-sh` or run the queries at http://console.neo4j.org and click `Result Details`. If you have an index like `:User(name)` it is more efficient to include the users name in the `MATCH`.

Comment: @jjaderberg you are absolutely right. It does not take care of the case you mentioned. I would change my query to MATCH (u:User)-[:IN]->(g)
WITH collect(u) AS groupUsers,g
WITH groupUsers,g, length(groupUsers) AS groupCount
WHERE ALL (x IN groupUsers 
           WHERE x.name IN ['u1', 'u2']) AND groupCount=2
RETURN g but now yours makes more sense

Comment: @jjaderberg, I can use Luanne's for 3 or more users. I'm not sure how to do it with yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a criterion like "both 'u1' and 'u2' are members of the group and there are only two members of the group". Here's one way to say that in cypher

```
MATCH (:User { name:'u1' })-[:IN]->(g)<-[:IN]-({ name:'u2' })
MATCH g<-[:IN]-(m)
WITH g, collect(m) AS members
WHERE length(members)= 2
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thanks @jjaderberg but unfortunately it didn't return any results.

Comment: @GrantShield My bad, not sure why I thought that would work. I've changed the query, now it should do what I had intended.

Comment: @GrantShield you should pick this answer, sorry. Mine clearly missed a case.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @jjaderberg! I'll check out the query profiler too.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could query for 3 or more users. Will try work it out but choosing the other answer for now...

Comment: Ok, I see you can use the WHERE clause: `WHERE (g)<-[:IN]-({ name:'u2' }) AND...`. Thanks again for your help!